# Can I define a custom tag in Office 365?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office

Is there a way to create a custom tag in MS Office 365 data such as Word, Excel, Powerpoint files?

I am envisioning something "invisble" when I print the Word Document, but still machine-readable for a parser.  There was something like "smart tags" previously, but this seems to be left behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Actions` as was suggested on the [Smart Tag in Word 2016](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ae7098b7-d90d-4bbd-86f4-fd2d9b6a7ee6/smart-tag-in-word-2016?forum=vsto) page. In all other case you'll have to introduce your own system to mark document pieces, so your add-in could react to them.